# Is there a format or a way I can set my dates into this format: mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Right now im getting this format from my localhost: 1990-01-01T16:00:00.000Z.

I just want my format to 01/01/1990 and be able to set it to my form.

My js is...

```
    var vm;
  vm = this;
  vm.data = {};
  vm.data.dob = memberData.dob;
```

and my HTML form is...

```
div class="item item-icon-left"><i class="icon ion-calendar assertive"></i><span  class="label">Birthday</span><span class="item-note">
              <input type="date" name="dob" placeholder="Birthday" ng-model="profile.data.dob"  required="required" style="background-color:transparent; padding-right:-100px; margin-top: 10px;" />
```

Comment: date.toLocaleString('en-US').substr(0, 10)

Comment: NOTE: toLocaleString doesn't work with IE < 11 or Safari at all

Comment: what do you mean? like vm.data.dob.date.toLocaleString('en-US').substr(0, 10) ? im kinda new in js...

Comment: You can use the built in date filter.  In your controller it would be: `$filter('yourdate')(date, format, timezone)`.  Don't forget to pass in the $filter service.  See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the built in [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for this, if you're formatting a string for a text input.

However, you need to remember that input is a directive in AngularJS and the date type input expects a date object for the model.  They won't work if you pass a string.  From the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D):

> The model must always be a Date object, otherwise Angular will throw
>   an error. Invalid Date objects (dates whose getTime() is NaN) will be
>   rendered as an empty string.

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($filter) {

  var date = '1990-01-01T16:00:00.000Z';
  this.dt = $filter('date')(date, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
  this.dt2 = new Date(date);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl as vm">
    <label>Text Input: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.dt" /></label>
    <label>Date Input: <input  type="date" ng-model="vm.dt2" /></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use the filters to format your dates any way that you want.  I originally used the 'shortDate' option just because it's internationalized automatically.  So now I changed it to format it as mm/dd/yyyy.  However, I think you don't realize that **you can't pass a string to a date input**.  It expects a date object.  Therefore, all you have to do is take your ISO formatted date from your backend and create a new date object from it: `new Date('1990-01-01T16:00:00.000Z');`.  See the updated example.

Comment: I seem to be getting this Error "Unknown provider: dobFilterProvider <- dobFilter". I have included the $filter in my controller and the angularjs.

Comment: And, just FYI.  If you were trying to do this with just a strictly HTML5 date input (not in AngularJS), you'd have to format the date as: YYYY-MM-DD, because Americans, like me, would naturally put the month first, whereas most of the rest of the world puts the day of the month first.  Therefore to standardize, the input only accepts values in YYYY-MM-DD format and then the browser handles the formatting from there.

Comment: Hard to debug without seeing what you're doing.  Can you either provide a demo or update your question with the controller code?

Comment: ok i just did things manually;  var year, month, day;
  var dob1 = new Date(vm.data.dob);
  day = dob1.getDate();
  month = dob1.getMonth() + 1;
  year = dob1.getFullYear();
  vm.data.dob = new Date (month + '-' + day + '-' + year);
  console.log(vm.data.dob);
  console.log(day);
  console.log(month); detected by the Input Type = date;. lol. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: I just thought that whenever I change stuff in the localstorage the UI is also changed, so I just changed the value of the localstorage date and get day ,year and month and then replaced it with those values and then converted it to a new Date(); so it can be detected by the Input Type = date.